# AJAX request in for loop returns results out of order

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop

I'm trying to append 10 images into my `#container`, in the same order that they're being requested but for reasons I don't understand they're being returned out of order.

I'm currently getting the URLs via a `for` loop and passing them into an AJAX request as per below:

```
for (i = 0; i < $links.length; i++) {
    link = $links.eq(i).attr('href');

    // Appends anchor into #container
    $('#container').append('<a href="' + link + '" class="tile"><p>' + $links.eq(i).text() + '</p></a>');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: link
    }).done(function (data) {
        var $data = $(data);
        $('#container').append($data.find('img').eq(0));
    });
};
```

Any insight into how I could fix or better this would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour because the requests are asynchronous. They may be fired in the order you require, but the response time is entirely at the mercy of the server and how long it takes to process each request.

For example, say you make 3 requests. #1 takes 150ms to complete, #2 200ms and #3 75ms. Your `done()` handler would then execute the requests in order 3, 1, 2.

If you depend on the responses being processed in a specific order you will need to amend your code to send all data in a single request so that the response can be formatted as you require.

The use of `async: false` may create the behaviour you expect, but it is incredibly bad practice to use, and the above solution would be much more preferable.